# 17.10 Super key to open applications

Tags: shortcut-keys, 17.10

I've upgraded my laptop from 17.04 to 17.10 and the super key no longer brings up the applications menu. Does anyone have any idea how I can change this?

Shortcuts menu doesn't let me change Super + A to just Super.

Edit: I'm running the standard desktop version of Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.

The best solution was installing the following extension:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1198/start-overlay-in-application-view/

Works like a charm! :)

Comment: 1. I cant install this "gnome extension plugin" on my firefox (ubuntu 18 fresh installed). 2. I dont know how to install this extension from archieve. Its looks like better install Gnome tweak https://askubuntu.com/a/1011890/457803 works fine and faster to do this

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this problem using Gnome Tweaks.

1. Install Gnome Tweaks from Ubuntu Software
2. Launch `Tweaks`
3. Select `Keyboard & Mouse`
4. For `Overview Shortcut` select `Right Super` (instead of `Left Super`)

Comment: Ubuntu 18, works fine! thanks. Why they dont include it in standart package of Ubuntu or Gnome, its must have preference =( any time when i reinstall ubuntu i need to fix this problems ;(

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if you are running standard Ubuntu or some other flavour.

If it's the standard version with the new Gnome interface, when you press the super key you should see a vertical bar on the left of the screen showing your favourite app icons.  The bottom icon in that bar will look like a grid.  If you click that, you should get all your installed applications displayed.

Comment: Thanks for responding, it's standard desktop ubuntu, I'll update the question.

I don't see any bar on the left, but ideally I just want to see the applications. It looks more like an alt-tab option at the moment.